Configure the Jenkins agent to use different versions of the JDK
I am setting up Jenkins via Docker image jenkins/jenkins:2.462.3-alpine-jdk21. At the moment I have added agent jenkins/inbound-agent:3283.v92c105e0f819-1-alpine3.20-jdk21 and I have a problem that I can't use any other JDK version other than 21. Now it looks like this (when running the pipeline):
/home/jenkins/agent/tools/hudson.model.JDK/jdk8/jdk8u432-b06/bin/java -version
openjdk version "21.0.5" 2024-10-15 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-21.0.5+11 (build 21.0.5+11-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-21.0.5+11 (build 21.0.5+11-LTS, mixed mode)

But if I run a similar command in the agent container, it returns what I expect:
/home/jenkins/agent/tools/hudson.model.JDK/jdk8/jdk8u432-b06/bin/java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_432"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Temurin)(build 1.8.0_432-b06)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Temurin)(build 25.432-b06, mixed mode)

Tell me what could be wrong, because the JDK version for alpine is OpenJDK8U-jdk_x64_alpine-linux_hotspot_8u432b06.tar.gz?

I tried to explicitly set the version via /home/jenkins/agent/tools/hudson.model.JDK/jdk8/jdk8u432-b06/bin/java

I tried to specify the version in the stage via
tools {
    jdk 'jdk8'
}


I tried to set the version via
withEnv(["JAVA_HOME=/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/jdk8/jdk8u432-b06", "PATH=/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/jdk8/jdk8u432-b06/bin:${env.PATH}"])

I tried to set the version via
script {
    def jdkPath = tool name: 'jdk8', type: 'jdk'
    env.JAVA_HOME = jdkPath
    env.PATH = "${jdkPath}/bin:${env.PATH}"
}



The result is always the same, it uses JDK21.

If your Docker image or Jenkins environment already includes the required Java versions, you can configure Jenkins to use those paths by following these steps:
Steps Eg:
Go to Manage Jenkins > Global Tool Configuration.
Scroll to JDK and configure multiple JDKs:
JDK 8: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
JDK 11: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
TO use specific jdk, for freestyle
Enable JDK Selection:
Under the Build Environment section, check the box for "Use a specific JDK".
For declarative
pipeline {
agent any
tools {
jdk 'JDK11' // Replace 'JDK11' with the name of the JDK in Global Tool Configuration
}
stages {
stage('Build') {
steps {
sh 'java -version' // Command to verify the JDK being used
}
}
}
}
